# What does "Counts for qgroup ... are different" mean and how to fix it?

Tags: btrfs

I've been using btrfs for my primary file system for a Linux Mint 20 install I did a couple of months ago. Today I had reason to want to extend the partition the btrfs filesystem is on, and `gparted` did a filesystem check beforehand and then refused to extend the partition due to file system errors. So I did a `btrfs check` on the partition (while it was unmounted; booted from a "Live CD" USB stick) and got 13 errors saying `Counts for qgroup id 0/1234 are different` (with varying ID numbers; below).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs#Quota_groups), quota groups (qgroups) relate to limiting the size of snapshots. I've only done snapshots indirectly via `timeshift` so I'm afraid I don't know the details there. I can get rid of those snapshots if needed.

What do the errors mean, and how do I fix them? The manpage for `btrfs check` is really quite adamant about not using the `--repair` option without knowing what you're doing...which I don't. :-)

Here is the output of the `btrfs check` *(whitespace may have been slightly mangled, I copied and pasted to a Google Docs doc while running the Live CD and didn't think about whitespace)*:

```
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/sda3
UUID: 1cf835e0-2f64-493e-ae63-035dbd007cc3
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space cache
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups
Counts for qgroup id: 0/256 are different
our:     referenced 15140220928 referenced compressed 15140220928
disk:        referenced 15170641920 referenced compressed 15170641920
diff:        referenced -30420992 referenced compressed -30420992
our:     exclusive 847220736 exclusive compressed 847220736
disk:        exclusive 847220736 exclusive compressed 847220736
Counts for qgroup id: 0/257 are different
our:     referenced 1181160329216 referenced compressed 1181160329216
disk:        referenced 1181156818944 referenced compressed 1181156818944
diff:        referenced 3510272 referenced compressed 3510272
our:     exclusive 1181160329216 exclusive compressed 1181160329216
disk:        exclusive 1181156818944 exclusive compressed 1181156818944
diff:        exclusive 3510272 exclusive compressed 3510272
Counts for qgroup id: 0/1026 are different
our:     referenced 9243115520 referenced compressed 9243115520
disk:        referenced 9243115520 referenced compressed 9243115520
our:     exclusive 696569856 exclusive compressed 696569856
disk:        exclusive 682135552 exclusive compressed 682135552
diff:        exclusive 14434304 exclusive compressed 14434304
Counts for qgroup id: 0/2848 are different
our:     referenced 13068500992 referenced compressed 13068500992
disk:        referenced 13098921984 referenced compressed 13098921984
diff:        referenced -30420992 referenced compressed -30420992
our:     exclusive 1556750336 exclusive compressed 1556750336
disk:        exclusive 1556750336 exclusive compressed 1556750336
Counts for qgroup id: 0/2882 are different
our:     referenced 14523535360 referenced compressed 14523535360
disk:        referenced 14553956352 referenced compressed 14553956352
diff:        referenced -30420992 referenced compressed -30420992
our:     exclusive 1373368320 exclusive compressed 1373368320
disk:        exclusive 1373368320 exclusive compressed 1373368320
Counts for qgroup id: 0/2935 are different
our:     referenced 14761443328 referenced compressed 14761443328
disk:        referenced 14791864320 referenced compressed 14791864320
diff:        referenced -30420992 referenced compressed -30420992
our:     exclusive 232054784 exclusive compressed 232054784
disk:        exclusive 232054784 exclusive compressed 232054784
Counts for qgroup id: 0/2937 are different
our:     referenced 14889074688 referenced compressed 14889074688
disk:        referenced 14919495680 referenced compressed 14919495680
diff:        referenced -30420992 referenced compressed -30420992
our:     exclusive 244756480 exclusive compressed 244756480
disk:        exclusive 244756480 exclusive compressed 244756480
Counts for qgroup id: 0/2951 are different
our:     referenced 15147077632 referenced compressed 15147077632
disk:        referenced 15177498624 referenced compressed 15177498624
diff:        referenced -30420992 referenced compressed -30420992
our:     exclusive 239132672 exclusive compressed 239132672
disk:        exclusive 239132672 exclusive compressed 239132672
Counts for qgroup id: 0/2953 are different
our:     referenced 15282089984 referenced compressed 15282089984
disk:        referenced 15312510976 referenced compressed 15312510976
diff:        referenced -30420992 referenced compressed -30420992
our:     exclusive 229437440 exclusive compressed 229437440
disk:        exclusive 229437440 exclusive compressed 229437440
Counts for qgroup id: 0/2965 are different
our:     referenced 14960881664 referenced compressed 14960881664
disk:        referenced 14991302656 referenced compressed 14991302656
diff:        referenced -30420992 referenced compressed -30420992
our:     exclusive 221765632 exclusive compressed 221765632
disk:        exclusive 221765632 exclusive compressed 221765632
Counts for qgroup id: 0/2970 are different
our:     referenced 15028105216 referenced compressed 15028105216
disk:        referenced 15058526208 referenced compressed 15058526208
diff:        referenced -30420992 referenced compressed -30420992
our:     exclusive 226172928 exclusive compressed 226172928
disk:        exclusive 226172928 exclusive compressed 226172928
Counts for qgroup id: 0/2971 are different
our:     referenced 15051378688 referenced compressed 15051378688
disk:        referenced 15081799680 referenced compressed 15081799680
diff:        referenced -30420992 referenced compressed -30420992
our:     exclusive 221945856 exclusive compressed 221945856
disk:        exclusive 221945856 exclusive compressed 221945856
Counts for qgroup id: 0/2972 are different
our:     referenced 15066845184 referenced compressed 15066845184
disk:        referenced 15097266176 referenced compressed 15097266176
diff:        referenced -30420992 referenced compressed -30420992
our:     exclusive 244789248 exclusive compressed 244789248
disk:        exclusive 244789248 exclusive compressed 244789248
found 1210188607488 bytes used, error(s) found
total csum bytes: 1175644964
total tree bytes: 5449875456
total fs tree bytes: 3953197056
total extent tree bytes: 239271936
btree space waste bytes: 804352655
file data blocks allocated: 7189404340224
 referenced 1204569280512
```

Answer (score 2):

It means the quota group ids are different. A quick solution that fixed it for me was to `mount /dev/sda3 /mnt` then turn off quota with `btrfs quota disable /mnt` and turn it on again with `btrfs quota enable /mnt`. Error message gone.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me in OpenSuse Tumbleweed Slowroll with transactional update creating a new default snapshot/subvolume